# SVG incorrectly rendered when document is served as application/xhtml+xml

Tags: html, css, svg, xhtml, units-of-measurement

I'd like to put some inline SVG into a HTML5 document. While researching and testing, Firefox and Chrome (patched up to date at the time of writing this) showed weird behavior when the document was served using different MIME types.

First please consider the following minimal HTML5 document **which works as expected *if it is served as `text/html`***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
div {
  background-color: orange;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
circle {
  stroke: black;
  fill: black;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
  <svg width="28pt" height="28pt" viewbox="0 0 14 14">
    <circle cx="7" cy="7" r="6" />
  </svg>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

As [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nL7jfkb/) shows, this is rendered as expected: The black circle fills the `svg` and the wrapping `div` nearly completely in height (the center of the circle is at `7`, i.e at half height, because the user coordinate system goes from `0` to `14` in height).

Now please consider the same document **in XHTML5 variant *and let it serve as `application/xhtml+xml`***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
div {
  background-color: orange;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
circle {
  stroke: black;
  fill: black;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28pt" height="28pt" viewbox="0 0 14 14">
    <circle cx="7" cy="7" r="6" />
  </svg>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I can't provide a JSFiddle for that one because I don't know how to make JSFiddle (or similar sites) serve a document as `application/xhtml+xml`.

Anyway, the black circle now is only about one third the height of its containing `svg` and wrapping `div`. It seems that Firefox and Chrome ***wrongly assume all user coordinates in the `svg` to be in pixel units*** in that document / MIME mode, i.e. the `viewbox` attribute is ignored, and hence I can't work with user coordinates for the items in the `svg`.

This is sort of a problem for me because I'd really like to keep serving my documents as `application/xhtml+xml`.

Could anybody explain the reason for that weird behavior and how to get around it?

Comment: Thanks and +1. You are absolutely right. I'll immediately correct my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive. HTML is not.

The svg attribute name is `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Upvoted and accepted ... I have to admit I would never have come to that idea because nearly no site I have come across during my research did show the correct spelling of the SVG attributes